# DM user reason they got banned

Tags: discord, bots

So at the moment I'm new to coding but I want to learn how to make a bot DM the user the reason they got banned before they actually get banned. I'm not too sure how to implement it into this code but if you could help me out I'd appreciate it. I have a kick command that sends the message before they get kicked but I don't know how to make it also like the ban command.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command bans a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.ban();
            message.channel.send("User has been banned");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You couldn't ban that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this to work?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: oh alright I'll post everything that's happened and what I've tried. I'm just trying to learn how to make it DM someone because there is no tutorials on youtube on how to do this. So I'm just trying to get someone to teach me on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can dm the user the reason for the ban you can be more creative with the reason sending like make it embed this is the basic reason sender.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command bans a member!",
    execute(message, args, prefix){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        if(!reason || reason.length <= 1){
           reason = "No Reason Was Provided."
        }

        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.send(`You Have been banned because of ${reason}`)
            memberTarget.ban();

            message.channel.send("User has been banned");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You couldn't ban that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```

> Run Command Like: +ban @User#0001 Reason